# How do i pass a method a string a return an integer (NetBeans)?

Tags: methods, combobox, jcombobox, calculator

I am creating a resistor calculator in `Java` using `NetBeans`. Say for example a 4 band resistor; The user enters the colours via 4 different `comboboxes` and the different colours are assigned an integer value according to the IEC Resistor Color Code Standards. So entering Brown, Black, Red in the `comboboxes` should return 1k Ohms.

```
int valBrown1, valBlack2, valRed3;
if (firstBand.getSelectedItem() == "Brown")
{
    valBrown1 = 10;
}
if (secondBand.getSelectedItem() == "Black")
{
    valBlack2 = 0;
}
if (secondBand.getSelectedItem() == "Black")
{
    valBlack2 = 0;
}
else if (thirdBand.getSelectedItem() == "Red")
{
    valRed3 = 10;
}
```

I need help finding a function that works kind of like this....:

```
ohmicValue(Colour1, Colour2, Colour3)
{
     int finalOhms;
     finalOhms = ((Colour1+Colour2)*Colour3);
     return(finalOhms);
}
```

Colour1,2&3 should be the integer values corresponding the colour chosen in the `combobox`.
Here is a [link](http://www.digikey.com/us/en/mkt/calculators/4-band-resistors.html) of what the finished version should look like